# Parser error on SOAP Envelope Node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm trying to create a simple  flow with soapInput, SoapExtract, SoapEnvelope and SoapReply Nodes. On SOAP extract node I'm saving the extracted envelope to default LocalEnvironment and with SoapEnvelope I want to add the envelope which I extracted earlier with soap extract node. Its throwing an error at SoapEnvelope node saying invalid parser. (Its throwing BIP 3171)

Below is the BIP 3171 error code description.
BIP3171
A message using an incorrect parser () was detected in node: 2
Severity
20 : Error
Explanation
Only the following parsers are allowed: mrm,xmlns,xmlnsc
Response
None.

Please help.